# Sparklyr split strings

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I have a file with several lines. For example

```
A               B       C    
awer.ttp.net    Code    554
abcd.ttp.net    Code    747
asdf.ttp.net    Part    554
xyz.ttp.net     Part    747
```

I want to make a command in spark in R using sparklyr library with statement to split just column A of the table and I want a new row added to the table D, with values awer, abcd, asdf, and xyz.

I have tried

```
data_2 %>% sdf_mutate(node2=ft_regex_tokenizer(data_2, input.col = "A", output.col = "D", pattern="[.]")) %>% sdf_register("mutated")
```

And then I try

```
mut_trial %>% mutate(E=D[[1]])
```

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'D' not found.

I'm not sure if Im doing this the right way but wanted to see if there's any other function to use or if theres a way to fix this function to do what I want.

Answer (score -1):

The code is in the scala spark hope you get the idea and convert it in SparkR

```
import spark.implicits._
val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  ("awer.ttp.net","Code", 554),
  ("abcd.ttp.net","Code", 747),
  ("asdf.ttp.net","Part", 554),
  ("xyz.ttp.net","Part", 747)
)).toDF("A","B","C")

data.withColumn("D", split($"A", "\\.")(0)).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+------------+----+---+----+
|A           |B   |C  |D   |
+------------+----+---+----+
|awer.ttp.net|Code|554|awer|
|abcd.ttp.net|Code|747|abcd|
|asdf.ttp.net|Part|554|asdf|
|xyz.ttp.net |Part|747|xyz |
+------------+----+---+----+
```

Hope this helped!